# Unable to import "pytz" module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytz

I have installed `pytz` package in PyCharm IDE but when I import the module it's giving an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/saika/PycharmProjects/Demo/Demo.py", line 2, in <module>     
import pytz
File "C:\Users\saika\PycharmProjects\Demo\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pytz\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
from pytz.tzinfo import unpickler, BaseTzInfo
File "C:\Users\saika\PycharmProjects\Demo\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pytz\tzinfo.py", line 3, in <module>
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo

  ImportError: cannot import name 'datetime'
```

What should I do?

Comment: If you named a file `datetime.py`, don't do that.

Comment: no i didn't named any file  datetime.py